# Add two value into array's cell

Tags: c++, vector

How can i push two values to a vector and reach both seperatly ?

I am try to do 1 A | 2 A |3 B | 4 C   each one is in the one cell.

Is that possible to do that ?

Comment: `A` is not a number(in the conventional decimal base). It is also not clear what do you mean by `1 A` is one cell. What is the type of your vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `std::vector<std::pair<int, char>>` (substitute the types of `1` and `A` for `int` and `char`, respectively).

This is how you could fill the vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> vec;

vec.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 'A'));
```

And this is how you access its contents:

```
int theOne = vec[0].first;
char theA = vec[0].second;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::pair` in your vector.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the std class pair, which simply regroup two elements :

```
std::pair< T1 , T2 > p ;
```

you can access T1 and T2 by using

```
p.first ;
p.second ;
```

then here it would do

```
vector< pair< int , char > >
```